# Swift Core Data preset values

Tags: swift, core-data

Is there a way to set some preset values to core data?
Basically adding some default values not editable and equal for everyone?

Thank you!

This is how I am fetching data:

```
func attemptFetch(){
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Course> = Course.fetchRequest()
    let dataSort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "title", ascending: true)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [dataSort]


    let controller = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

    controller.delegate = self
    self.controller = controller

    do {
        try controller.performFetch()
    } catch {
        let error = error as NSError
        print("\(error.debugDescription)")
    }
}
```

and this is how i am getting the array:

```
if let objs = controller.fetchedObjects, objs.count > 0 {
        ....
}
```

Comment: How many preset values to add to the core data? The answer will depend on this

Comment: More or less 15 and each one contains 4 images, title subtitle and some other text

Comment: Okay should be no problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have two options that I can think of. Just display it or actually add it.

1. Display it. Take the array your using for CoreData display and add the data with static values. I think this is the easiest.

```
var CoreDataStringArray = [String]()
var CoreDataImage1Array = [UIImage]()

func fetchData() {

//Static values

CoreDataStringArray = ["Item 1", "Item 2", Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5"]
CoreDataImage1Array = [UIImage(named: "item1"),UIImage(named: "item2"),UIImage(named: "item3"),UIImage(named: "item4"),UIImage(named: "item5")]

//Now fetch the Core Data Values and the user will see a full list of them mixed together.

    }
```

2. You can add them on the first launch of the app. This how I save them, I run a for loop to siphon through each one.

//Inside Class (import CoreData above)

```
    let moc = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let openedbefore = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "openedbefore")

if openedbefore == false {
 //Add data

    var CoreDataStringArray = ["Item 1", "Item 2", Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5"]
    var CoreDataImage1Array = [UIImage(named: "item1"),UIImage(named: "item2"),UIImage(named: "item3"),UIImage(named: "item4"),UIImage(named: "item5")]



     for index in 0...CoreDataStringArray.count-1 {
        let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Entity", in: moc)

        let item = Entity(entity: entityDescription!, insertInto: moc)

        item.name = "\(CoreDataStringArray[index])"
        item.image = UIImagePNGRepresentation(CoreDataImage1Array[index]) as! NSData

        do {
            try moc.save() // Save the static values to CoreData
        } catch {
            return
        }
     }
  }

  UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "openedbefore")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer... just one more question... if i already have them inside the simulator is there a way to make them permanent or i ave to write the arrays?

Comment: If their in the simulator it does not matter, If you try and run code when you publish the app it will not have access to the images. They must be attached in someway to the actual app.

Comment: so the only way is write the array... problem is that is one entity with 24 field and i have 15 values... which makes 24 array and 15 values each...

Comment: For string data it can be typed in your code, for images added to your Image folder library but there must be a copy of it in your app. The array is just a way of collecting the data together. I really recommend the first option as it requires less run time. and is really easy to work with.

Comment: ok... I have update my question to show how i am fetching the data... you mean to add the array in that function?

Comment: No, I'm just saying for preset data it must be inside your app or online (but this requires internet). You can just type your string data into your swift file.

Comment: ok... thought about it... but i was looking for a faster way... anyway.. thank for your help! i appreciate!

Comment: Is that okay? I don't think theres any other way at present. If that works feel free to mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: i believe i have to change route and use a csv file... because it would be too long to write every single array... but hey i think u're probably right there's no other way...